# the state value not changing

Tags: react-native, state, mobx, mobx-react

I am trying to change the value of my value state consistently using mobx as my state manager. I am using a conditional statement on the Change method to render "X" when "Y" and "Y" when "X", but onPRess= it just renders "Y" and doesn't revert back to "X" when clicked again. It's like the method just takes place once. Can anyone help please.

Here are the concerned codes:

imports main:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Image, Text, View, PermissionsAndroid, Platform, TouchableOpacity, PixelRatio, Modal, Button} from 'react-native';
import {widthPercentageToDP as wp, heightPercentageToDP as hp} from 'react-native-responsive-screen'
import MenuIcon from '../Navigation/MenuIcon'
import { createBottomTabNavigator, createAppContainer, createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation'
import {observable} from 'mobx';
import {observer} from 'mobx-react';
import StateStorage from "../StateStorage"
```

imports StateStorage (mobx):

```
import {observable, action} from 'mobx';

class StateStorage {
  @observable value="Y";

  @action Change() {
    this.value="Y" ? "X" : "Y";


    }

}
export default new StateStorage();
```

What is rendered:

```
@observer
class Home extends React.Component{
render(){
return(
    <View style={styles.container1}>


         <TouchableOpacity onPress= {() => StateStorage.Change()}>
    <Text style={{color:'white'}} >{StateStorage.value}</Text>
                      </TouchableOpacity>

                      <Text style={styles.welcome}>hfhdfjedhfeehfjeh</Text>


                      </View>
)

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made mistake in using `?` operator.

`this.value="Y" ? "X" : "Y";` This will always set value as "X" because "Y" is `true` but not `false`.

```
import {observable, action} from 'mobx';

class StateStorage {
  @observable value="Y";

  @action Change() {
    this.value= this.value === "Y" ? "X" : "Y";
  }
}
export default new StateStorage();
```